# Evaluating $\int_1^A x^{-\alpha} dx$ as $A\to\infty$

Tags: integration, infinity

> Suppose $\alpha$ is a constant, $A$ is a positive real number.
>
> (a) Find the value of $\int_1^A x^{-\alpha} dx$, for $A > 1$.
>
> (b) What is the answer of (a) when $A$ tends to inﬁnity?

For (a), I find out it's $\frac{1}{1-\alpha}( A^{1-\alpha} -1 )$

However, for (b) , I am not sure how would the answer in (a) change when A tends to infinity. Should I state that there are 4 cases ( $\alpha < 0$, $\alpha = 0$, $0 < \alpha < 1$,  $\alpha > 1$) and then work out how does the answer in (a) change accordingly?

Comment: Yes. For example, for $a<1$ you will have the exponent $1-a>0$. Therefore, $A^{1-a}\to+\infty$ as $A\to+\infty$. Note that you still need to solve (a) for the case $a=1$. The answer that you have for (a) doesn't apply in that case.

Comment: Did you mean to use $B$ somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The following expression: 
$$\frac{1}{1-\alpha}( A^{1-\alpha} -1 )$$

goes to infinity for $\alpha \in (-\infty, 1)$. It is finite and equal to $\frac{1}{\alpha-1}$ for $\alpha \in (1,\infty)$.
For $\alpha = 1$, the answer will be $ln(A)$ which goes to $\infty$ as $A\to\infty$.

Also for the first part, you have to take two cases. $\alpha = 1$ and $\alpha \neq 1$ because the resulting expression will change because of that.

For $\alpha \neq 1$ you get this expression:

$$\frac{1}{1-\alpha}( A^{1-\alpha} -1 )$$

And for $\alpha = 1$, you get

$$ln(A)$$

Comment: It goes to infinity for $\alpha\in(-\infty,1)$. For $\alpha=1$ it's not defined.

Comment: Thanks. Have edited to include it